# If p is a prime number of the form $4n+3$, show that we cannot solve $x^2\equiv -1\mod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

Hint: Use Fermat's Theorem that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ if $p \nmid a$. (I have no idea, but something in group theory should help)

Comment: You probably mean $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: $1^2 \equiv ... (\text{mod}\; p)$ The statement should be "$\ldots x^2 \equiv\ -1\; (\text{mod}\; p)$".

Comment: Ok, it's an error. "1" should be "-1", sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right theorem is that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$. Or equivalently that $x^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has no solution.

Let  $p=4k+3$.

Note that if $x$ is not divisible by $p$, then
$$(x^2)^{2k+1}=x^{4k+2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\tag{1}$$
 by Fermat's Theorem.

But if $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, then 
$$(x^2)^{2k+1}\equiv (-1)^{2k+1}\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$$
Since we cannot have $-1\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, this contradicts (1).

Comment: Thanks. But what if $p \mid x$?

Comment: @pxc3110 Then what is $x \pmod{p}$? And hnce $x^2 \pmod{p}$ is?

Comment: @pxc3110:  $p$ cannot divide $x$ if $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.  So if we assume that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, we are in the $\gcd(x,p)=1$ cse.

Answer (score 2):

A group theory flavoured hinted solution:

First, we can reduce the problem to showing there doesn't exists $\;x\in\Bbb F_p\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ s.t. $\;x^2=-1\;$ by passing from the integers (usual) arithmetic to arithmetic modulo $\;p\;$.

Second, since $\;x=0\in\Bbb F_p\implies x^2=0\neq-1\;$ , we can in fact assume we're working within the cyclic group $\;\Bbb F_p^*:=\Bbb F_p\setminus\{0\}\;$.

Now, suppose

$$\exists\,x\in\Bbb F_p^*\;\;s.t.\;\;x^2=-1\implies x^4=1$$

and since clearly $\;x\neq 1\;$ (why?),  we've then found an element of order four in $\;\Bbb F_p^*\;$ ....but this is absurd (why? Complete the proof).

Comment: Nice answer....! The corresponding multiplicative group has order $4n+2$ and 4 does not divide this number. So such an x cannot exist.. Right? ....

Answer (score 1):

The question is wrong dude. You will NOT be able to solve $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ is $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\equiv -1\pmod p\implies a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod p$ This could help classify the solvable congruences. And your question is wrong because $x\equiv 1\pmod p$works. $1$ is a quadratic residue mod every prime. And $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv (-1)^{2n+1}\equiv -1\pmod p$ hence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod p$ is not solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a typo. (Otherwise just take $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$.)

If you mean $x^2+1 \equiv 0$ is unsolvable, then here is a sketch of the proof.

Say $p\equiv3\pmod4$ and $p|a^2+b^2$. Then from Fermat's theorem, $p|a^{p-1}-b^{p-1}$. On the other hand, since $\dfrac{p-1}2$ odd, $p|a^2+b^2|\left(a^2\right)^{\frac{p-1}2}+\left(b^2\right)^{\frac{p-1}2}=a^{p-1}+b^{p-1}$. Thus $p|2a^{p-1}$ implying $p|a,b$. Therefore, $p$ must divide $a,b$ and the conclusion follows.